# setMainQmlFile`, rootObject and showExpanded are not members of QQmlApplicationEngine

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qt5.4

I've written this piece of code following some guys tutorial but I can't get it to run. The error says:

> setMainQmlFile`, rootObject and showExpanded are not members of
> QQmlApplicationEngine

What it's supposed to do is get a signal from QML and print out a message (in console). Basically I'm trying to integrate C++ and QML.

### EDIT

I've tried to replace some of the functions with some others that seemed appropriate (at least to me). I've also tried to find what to include so that these functions would work but with no luck.

```
   #include <QGuiApplication>
   #include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

   #include "qtquickglobal.h"
   #include <QQmlContext>
   #include "myclass.h"
   #include <QtCore>
   #include <QtDebug>
   #include <QQuickWindow>



int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    //Q_OBJECT;
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine viewer;

    viewer.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("Qt/Versuch2/main.qml")));

    myclass data;

    viewer.rootContext() ->setContextProperty("myclassData", &data);
    viewer.setMainQmlFile(QStringLiteral("qml/Versuch2/main.qml"));

    QObject *viewerobject = viewer.rootObject();

    QObject::connect(viewerobject, SIGNAL(qmlSignal(QString)), &data, SLOT(cppSlot(QString)));
            viewer.showExpanded();

    return app.exec();

}

void myclass::cppSlot(QString msg) {

    qDebug() <<QString ("Called the cpp slot with message: %1").arg(msg);
}
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where did you find you tutorial but, regarding Qt documentation, there is no such methods as `setMainQmlFile` nor `showExpanded` for [QQmlApplicationEngine](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlapplicationengine-members.html).

For `setMainQmlFile(...)`, try to use instead `setSource(...)`.

For `showExpanded()`, it's a `QWidget` function, and `QQmlApplicationEngine` do not inherit `QWidget`.

Regarding `rootObject()`, it might be a typo, you can use `rootObjects()` which return a `QList<QObject*>`.

Edit: Looks like you'll have to use the Qt Quick 2 Application wizard of Qt Creator in order to re-create that `QtQuick2ApplicationViewer` class used in the tutorial you found.

Comment: I tried using to replace seMainQmlFile with set source, the same thing.  The tutorial is here [link](http://qtvon0auf100.wordpress.com/2013/11/20/q_invokable-oder-wie-kann-ich-qt-funktionen-in-qml-benutzen/)

Comment: OK, so even if I can't understand German, here is what I found.
The tutorial never use `QQmlApplicationEngine` but `QtQuick2ApplicationViewer` which looks like a custom-made class.
So you will have to create that class or an equivalent.

Comment: I'm new to Qt and don't know that much but from what i've seen so far (documentation and other questions on the web) QtQuick2Applicationviewer was kinda "replaced" or something by QQmlApplicationEngine. Thnx for the effort though. :)

Comment: `QtQuick2ApplicationViewer` was generated by QtCreator in previous versions of Qt. The tutorial probably addresses Qt <= 5.2 or so. Indeed the current documentation has a [different example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-interactqmlfromcpp.html#connecting-to-qml-signals).

Just follow the code shown in this tutorial. Only, remember to add `#include <QQuickItem>` in the `main.cpp`: even if it is not shown in the code it MUST be added for the tutorial code to work.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Now that example helped me quite a bit, I've seen it earlier but didn't try it out. Now i got an error that says  "QQmlComponent: component is not ready". Thank You.

Comment: It perfectly works for me...did you depart from the QML code in the example? It could be possible that the component (i.e. our `Item`) is still loading. In that case you can wait for the `status` of the `QQuickView view` to reach the `QQuickView::Ready` state and only then setup the connection.

Comment: Actually none of the examples from that site work for me. The first part (left side) loading with QQmlComponent fails with error component not ready, the other one using QQuickView fails with example.exe has crashed.  I combined the code from the example i was following (the one in german) and the one you linked me to, that way i was able to make it work somehow. Somehow meaning it doesn't crash anymore but it says: _"If your example is using QML 2, (such as qmlscene) and the .qml file you loaded has 'import QtQuick 1.0' or 'import Qt 4.7', this error will occur"._ I'm not using either one .

Comment: The last error is due to the structure of the loaded file, mostly. It defines an `Item` as a top type whereas you have probably an `Window` or something similar? Got no more time right now. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for the effort. I'm kinda starting to suspect something with  Qt isn't right (installation maybe- I don't know). I've tried a great deal of examples and tutorials from the web - nothing works! Something's fishy here!

Comment: Ok. :) As a remainder, be careful with online tutorial: if they address an older version of Qt they could not work. Stick with the documentation examples. Moreover, search inside the `example` directory of your Qt installation folder: all the example inside the documentation should be included, even example about this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Using Qt 5.4.0 and Qt Creator 3.3.0, create New Project:

1. Click New Project
2. Qt Quick Application
3. Click Choose...
4. Name the project and select where to place it
5. Click Next
6. Select Qt Quick 2.4 from the drop-down menu
7. Click Next
8. Select desired Kit(s)
9. Click Next
10. Click Finish

---

Now You should see open main.qml file with following code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    MainForm {
        anchors.fill: parent
        mouseArea.onClicked: {
            Qt.quit();
        }

    }
}
```

---

Make changes to the file so that it looks like the following:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true

    //### New Code ###

    signal myQmlSignal(string msg)

    //################

    MainForm {
        anchors.fill: parent
        mouseArea.onClicked: {

            //### New Code ###
            //Replace "Qt.quit();" with

            console.log("Sending myQmlSignal from QML...");
            myQmlSignal("Hello from QML")

            //################
        }
    }
}
```

---

Add new class to Your project:

1. Right Mouse Click project name in Projects viewer
2. Click Add New...
3. Select C++ Class if not already selected
4. Click Choose...
5. In Class name filed enter "MyCppClass"
6. Set Base class to QObject
7. Click Next
8. Click Finish

---

Open mycppclass.h file, it should look like the following:

```
#ifndef MYCPPCLASS_H
#define MYCPPCLASS_H

#include <QObject>

class MyCppClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyCppClass(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MyCppClass();

signals:

public slots:
};

#endif // MYCPPCLASS_H
```

---

Make changes to mycppclass.h so it looks like this:

```
#ifndef MYCPPCLASS_H
#define MYCPPCLASS_H

#include <QObject>

//### New Code ###

#include <QDebug>

//################

class MyCppClass : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyCppClass(QObject *parent = 0);
    ~MyCppClass();

signals:

public slots:
    //### New Code ###

    void myCppSlot(const QString &msg);

    //################
};

#endif // MYCPPCLASS_H
```

---

Open mycppclass.cpp, which should look like this:

```
#include "mycppclass.h"

MyCppClass::MyCppClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

MyCppClass::~MyCppClass()
{

}
```

---

Change it to this:

```
#include "mycppclass.h"

MyCppClass::MyCppClass(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

MyCppClass::~MyCppClass()
{

}

void MyCppClass::myCppSlot(const QString &msg)
{
    //### New Code ###

    qDebug() << "Signal was received by C++. It contains follwoing message: " << msg;

    //################
}
```

---

Open main.cpp, which looks like this:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

---

And make following changes:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

//### New Code ###

#include "mycppclass.h"

//################

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    //### New Code ###

    MyCppClass myCppClass;

    QObject::connect(engine.rootObjects().takeFirst(), SIGNAL(myQmlSignal(QString)), &myCppClass, SLOT(myCppSlot(QString)));

    //################

    return app.exec();
}
```

---

Click big green triangle to compile and run Your application. Watch Application Output area, click Hello World, You should see following message being printed out:

*qml: Sending myQmlSignal from QML...*

*Signal was received by C++. It contains follwoing message:  "Hello from QML"*